# In the reopen votes of review queues section, what if an edited question should remain closed, but with a different reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For example, question X is marked as **too broad** (and already closed). After an edit (in the reopen votes section), it appears for review. Now, with that edit, it still should stay closed, but now it's a **duplicate**, not **too broad**. I didn't see any option to change the flag.

What do you think?